# What happens when the beta period for Cloud Firestore ends

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save some data in Cloud Firestore and use it as REST API but in the document it says:

> All REST API endpoints exist under the base URL https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/

When Firestore ends the beta version, will it change the base URL to, for example, https://firestore.googleapis.com/stable/.

What happens with my data in the beta version? Can I move all to use only stable version?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your concern?  I imagine you'll just change your URL prefix and move forward.

Comment: I use beta URL in my app and then Firebase release stable version with difference URL. Many users downloaded my app that used URL in beta version may not update and I can't control the data.

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that the original URL is just going to stop working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 01/31/19**

Cloud Firestore is no longer in Beta and has graduated to GA:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates

---

At the end of the beta period we will release the v1 GA endpoint at `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/`.

Note: Nothing changes in your database, just the endpoint our client libraries use to talk to it. Simply upgrading to the newest client library should be sufficient, or changing the endpoint URL if you use the API directly.

The existing `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/` endpoint will continue to operate at this time, but will be announced as deprecated with a >= 6 month grace period before it is discontinued.

Comment: Hey Dan, you mentioned "at the end of the beta period". When is Firestore planned to go stable? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no news during Google I/O (or did I miss something?)

Comment: Vasil, at the moment it seems Google is not going to reveal the milestones they have planned for the product. Let's hope we can have more information soon.

Comment: Hi @Robotec, I don't think we have, but that type of question is best posted on a Google group google-cloud-firestore-discuss@: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss